requiero visitar cada pestaña del notebook y apagar cada entry
un saludo.
Creo que es algo sencillo pero no logro hacerlo.
Necesito visitar cada pestaña del notebook y si el widget contenido alli es un ttk.entry, deshabilitarlo.
nota: al interior de cada pestaña hay muchos mas widget, pero para efectos de resumir y presentar el problema, coloco un código sencillo.
Mi código que no funciona es este.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

formulario = Tk()
formulario.geometry("500x400+200+200")

# crea el notebook
mp = ttk.Notebook(formulario, width=350, height=250)
pag1 = Frame(mp, bg='blue')
pag2 = Frame(mp, bg='red')
mp.add(pag1, text='compra')
mp.add(pag2, text='venta')
mp.place(x=25,y=25)

# crea los cajones
cajon1 = ttk.Entry(pag1)
cajon1.pack()
cajon2 = ttk.Entry(pag2)
cajon2.pack()

# recorre cada página del notebook y si encuentra un entry lo deshabilita
w: ttk.Widget
for i in mp.tabs():                         #recorre cada pestaña del notebook
    for w in mp.tab(i).winfo_children():    #recorre cada widget dentro de la página
        if w.winfo_class() == "TEntry":     #verifica si es un entry
            w.state(["disabled"])           #lo apaga

formulario.mainloop()


El método tabs() ya retorna una lista con el nombre del widget raiz de cada pestaña, simplemente usa el método nametowidget() para obtener la referencia al objeto Python correspondiente a ese widget:
for tab in mp.tabs():
    for widget in mp.nametowidget(tab).winfo_children():
        if widget.winfo_class() == "TEntry":
            widget.state(["disabled"])

